# Swift: Changing scenes with keyboard return button

Tags: swift

I'm new on swift so I'm having problems for coding. I would like to add an action to the return button on keyboard, so that when  I type it the keyboard would hide and the scene (the view) would change. So how can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add an action on UITextField return key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553396/how-to-add-an-action-on-uitextfield-return-key)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11553533/429427) discusses how to respond to `UITextField`'s return key, and [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) describes how to use segues to transition between storyboard scenes.

Comment: That's don't solve my problem cause it doesn't change scenes

Comment: The second link I provided describes how to change scenes in storyboards (or programmatically) using segues.

Comment: But it doesn't show how to change view pressing the return button in the keyboard.

Comment: No, the first link describes how to respond to the return key. Essentially, you need to implement `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `textFieldShouldReturn(_:)` method, and from within that method you will call `performSegueWithIdentifier("NextSceneIdentifier")` (if you have such a segue setup in your storyboard) or instantiate a new view controller and push to it using `presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)` (for a modal push) or `navigationController.pushViewController(_:animated:)` (for pushing onto the current nav stack).

Comment: My code is like this, and it isn't working:

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        if(textField == self.myTextField)
        {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            performSegueWithIdentifier("InitialView", sender: nil)
            return false
        }

        return true;
    }

Comment: The ViewDidLoad is like this:
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.myTextField.delegate = self
}

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with more specific details of the problem - as it is, it is unlikely to be answered and will probably be closed because it is very broad. Be clear about any errors or unexpected behaviour, indicate what you expect should happen, and include relevant code or steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry! My app run successfully ,my problem is that when I press the return button on keyboard the app close. I'm doing something wrong in my code and I don't know what. The "InitialView" identifier is the identifier of a segue that connect the textField with a ViewController, with a push.

Comment: If you follow my suggestion of editing your question with more specific details (by clicking "edit" above these comments), it may be salvaged and attract a response. For help writing a good question and improve your chances of getting an answer, see this section of the Help Center: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the below func

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    //textField code

        textField.resignFirstResponder()  //if desired
        performAction()
        return true
    }

func performAction() {

//action events
}
```

Research where i found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26288341/4056108)